# Knockoutjs Handlebars. Click binding to rendered JSON not working as expected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, handlebars.js

I have been struggling with this for a while now and can't get the result I'm expecting. Any help would be much appreciated. Here's the code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/12842/). What I am trying to do here is to iterate through the JSON containing products which can contain several messages, and render the messages and have each of them bound to their own click function. Instead what happens is that, as the code is run, the click function is triggered on its own and clicking the message link does nothing.

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: doTest">This binding works</a>
<!--The json is appended to these 2 ULs by class name-->
<ul class="product1"></ul>
<ul class="product2"></ul>
<script id="product-message-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
    <!-- code below should be binding to alertMessage(), but fails...-->
    <a href="#" data-bind="click:{{this.alertMessage}}">{{this.message}}</a>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

And here's the JS:

```
function init(){
    var self = this;
    self.view_model.doTest = function(){alert('this works')};
    self.product_messages_to_vm(json, view_model);
    self.render_product_messages(view_model);
}
var view_model= {};
var json = [{
        "id": "product1",
        "messages": [
            "p1 message1",
            "p1 message2"
            ]},{
        "id": "product2",
        "messages": [
            "p2 message1",
            "p2 message2"
        ]}];
//The Product object contains an observable array for messages and methods to add remove and save them
function Product(id, productMessages){
    this.productId = id;
    //make observableArray so when messages are removed, other messages can be notified
    this.messages = ko.observableArray([]);
    //iterate through messages and make them observable and add them to this product's messages 
    for(var i=0; i<productMessages.length; i++){                
        //this.messages().push(productMessages[i]);
        this.messages().push(new Message(productMessages[i])); 
    }
}
//message object 
function Message(msg){
    this.message = msg;
    this.alertMessage = function(){
        alert(this.message);
    }.bind(this);
}
//gets json messages and add them to the view model object
function product_messages_to_vm(json){
    var self = this;
    view_model.products = ko.observableArray([]);
    _.each(json, function(product,index){
        view_model.products().push( new self.Product(product.id, product.messages) );
    }); 
}
function render_product_messages(view_model){
    var self = this;
    _.each(view_model.products(), function(product){
        var template = Handlebars.compile($("#product-message-template").html());
        var messages = product.messages();
        var $message_html = $(template( messages ));
        //find element with the product class name, and append the compiled template into UI
        $( "." + product.productId ).append( $message_html );
    });
    ko.applyBindings(view_model);
}
init();
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I wanted to try to tackle it because I am just now learning [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html).

Before I could begin, there were a number of refactoring that I thought were necessary in order for me to understand the existing code. I removed a lot of `this` references which were confusedly used. Also, I in-lined the `product_messages_to_vm` and `render_product_messages` functions as these were not called multiple times.

Your specific problem has to do with the following snippet from your [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) template:

```
data-bind="click:{{this.alertMessage}}"
```

There seems to be some confusion here about what Knockout and what Handlebars are doing to this markup. Knockout expects a string that is a name of a method on your view model, and it will bind this method to the click event of the element. Handlebars will replace the Handlebars expression, `{{this.alertMessage}}`, with the corresponding value from your template data.

When Handlebars attempts to find the `alertMessage` value on each `message` object, it finds that the value is a function; Handlebars executes the function to obtain the return value (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12495934/3397771) for more details). This is why you are getting the alerts as the template is being rendered. Since each message's `alertMessage` method does not return a string, Knockout cannot bind the click event to a method.

What we need to do is to provide a string that is the name of the handler function we wish to bind to the click event:

```
data-bind="click: alertMessage"
```

However, we have a problem. This will work *only if* we have an `alertMessage` property on our `view_model` object. The `alertMessage` method we wish to call is nested deeply in our view_model; represented as a path, it would look like: /products/product[0]/messages/message[0]/alertMessage.

In order to have Knockout correctly bind this method, we must provide the correct path:

```
data-bind="click: products()[0].messages()[0].alertMessage"
```

This is better, but it only ever calls `alertMessage` on the first message of the first product, no matter which link we click. We need a way to dynamically assign the product and messages indexes in our template.

To do this, we must alter our template so that it takes a `product` object instead of a `messages` array and we must supply the product index:

```
<script id="product-message-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each product.messages}}
        <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: products()[{{../index}}].messages()[{{@index}}].alertMessage">{{this.message}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

This requires us to update our `template` call:

```
_.each(view_model.products(), function (product, index) {
    // TODO: Template ID should be renamed to 'product-template.
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#product-message-template").html());
    var $product_html = $(template({
        index: index,
        product: product
    }));
    $("." + product.productId).append($product_html);
});
```

And it works!

My final code with refactorings looks like this:

```
var json = [
    {
        "id": "product1",
        "messages": [
            "p1 message1",
            "p1 message2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "product2",
        "messages": [
            "p2 message1",
            "p2 message2"
        ]
    }
];

function Product (id, productMessages) {
    this.productId = id;
    this.messages = ko.observableArray([]);

    for (var i = 0; i < productMessages.length; i++) {
        this.messages().push(new Message(productMessages[i])); 
    }
}

function Message (msg) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.alertMessage = function () {
        alert(this.message);
    }.bind(this);
}

(function init () {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#product-template").html());
    var view_model = {
        products: ko.observableArray([]),
        doTest: function () {
            alert('this works');
        }
    };

    _.each(json, function (product, index) {
        var next_product = new Product(product.id, product.messages);
        var $product_html = $(template({
            index: index,
            product: next_product
        }));

        view_model.products().push(next_product);
        $('#Products').append($product_html);
    });

    ko.applyBindings(view_model);
})();
```

And the updated HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: doTest">This binding works</a>
<div id="Products"></div>

<script id="product-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul class="{{product.productId}}">
        {{#each product.messages}}
            <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: products()[{{../index}}].messages()[{{@index}}].alertMessage">{{this.message}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

A functioning JS Fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/76484/rpnt4qLb/2/).

Although this code works, I think a *much* better solution to the problem is to use the [foreach binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) provided by Knockout, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20350888/3397771) by [Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2161269/damien).

I will not provide here the code for such a solution, but I *will* link to a [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/dLcvhL38/).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the using of a template engine is way too complicated for what you are trying to do.

So, I simplify your code by using more knockout possibilities.
Now the view is  :

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: products">
        <div data-bind="foreach: messages"> <a data-bind="click: alertMessage, text : message" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the view model :

```
//The Product object contains an observable array for messages and methods to add remove and save them
function Product(id, productMessages) {
    this.productId = id;
    this.messages = ko.observableArray();
    this.messages(ko.utils.arrayMap(productMessages, function (pm) {
        return new Message(pm);
    }));
}

//message object 
function Message(msg) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.alertMessage = function () {
        alert(this.message);
    };
}

var ViewModel = function (raw) {
    var self = this;    
    self.products = ko.utils.arrayMap(json, function (p) {
        return new Product(p.id, p.messages);
    });
};
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/12857/)

Comment: The reason I am using Handlebars is that there are more HTML elements than what I pasted here, I removed them to make the code more readable. Thanks for the reply, I'll go with this implementation for now and hopefully can get it to work with Handlebars soon.

Comment: Your solution doesn't really fit the problem, because it prints out all the messages into one containing div rather than into their corresponding parent elements, the ul class="product1" elements. Thanks anyway :)