# Ember.js check if value is in array attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I have a Game model like this:

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    numbers: DS.attr(),
    drawnNumbers: DS.attr()
});
```

The content of `numbers` is

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
            16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
            31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,
            46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,
            61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75]
```

And the `drawnNumbers` attribute is a empty array (by default)

My view loops over all numbers

```
{{#each number in numbers}}
    <li data-number="{{number}}" class="number"><a>{{number}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

When a number exists in the drawnNumbers array I want to add a class `active`.

How would I go and do this?

Comment: Native javascript: [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: But I can't do any javascript in my templates. I need a computed property or something I think.

Comment: Ohh it uses Handlebars. I've used that before. See [SO 12492701](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12492701/758177)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to create an item controller which decorates each item while iterating over them, then add the logic there.  After which you'll use bind-attr to add conditional logic of when to show active.

#### Template

```
<ul>
  {{#each item in numbers itemController='foo'}}
    <li {{bind-attr class='isActive:active'}}>{{item.model}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

#### Route/Controller

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      numbers:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
            16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
            31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,
            46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,
            61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75],
      drawNumbers:[2,6,13]
     };
  }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

});

App.FooController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs:['index'], // stating I need the index controller, which has drawNumbers
  drawNumbers: Em.computed.alias('controllers.index.drawNumbers'),
  isActive:function(){
    var item = this.get('model'),
        drawNumbers = this.get('drawNumbers');

    return drawNumbers.indexOf(item)>=0;
  }.property('model')
})
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zedogayi/2/edit

Comment: After tweaking it a bit for my actual code. This worked just fine! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a custom component.

```
App.DrawNumberComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  number: null, 
  drawNumbers: null,

  tagName: 'li',
  attributeBindings: ['number'],
  classNameBindings: ['active'],

  active: function(){
   return this.get('drawNumbers').indexOf(this.get('number')) !==-1;

  }.property('drawNumbers.each', 'number')

});


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/draw-number">
   <a>{{number}}</a>
  </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each number in numbers}}
      {{draw-number number=number drawNumbers=controller.drawNumbers}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nuraj/1/edit