# Assign value to a locals variable in keystonejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, keystonejs

In keystonejs (a node cms), I am using handlebars as templating engine in keystonejs. In handlebar file, I am using #each to iterate through an array.

```
 {{#each data.positions}}
      <h1 onclick = "callFunction()"> {{title}} </h1>
 {{/each}}
```

Here I want to call a function within route, How can I do it?

Other way that is coming in my mind to to initialize locals variable. Like I have a variable locals.selectedPositionIndex in route file and I want to assign @index value of specific h1 element to this variable when any h1 element is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You could include a script at the bottom of your Handlebars template and include the function there:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Code here
  })
</script>
```

Alternatively, there is a question here with a useful answer:
[Passing a function into a Handlebars template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492701/passing-a-function-into-a-handlebars-template)

I have amended the answer from the above question to work with KeystoneJS:

In your view you can assign your function to **locals**:

```
locals.func = function () {
  // Code here
};
```

Then you will need to create a Handlebars helper in */templates/views/helpers/index.js*:

```
_helpers.stringifyFunc = function(fn) {
  return new hbs.SafeString("(" + fn.toString().replace(/\"/g,"'") + ")()");
};
```

You can then use this in your Handlebars template:

```
<h1 onclick="{{ stringifyFunc func }}">{{ title }}</h1>
```

I hope this helps.